# How can a future observation being predicted even if under sample independency (posterior predictive distribution)?

Tags: bayesian, predictive-models, posterior

I was reading https://people.stat.sc.edu/Hitchcock/stat535slidesday18.pdf and I came across with:

[image]

It gives us an way to get a distribution for a new observation called for $x_{new}$ given the past sample values $\mathbf{x}$ but $x_{new}$ independs from $\mathbf{x}$ so $P(x_{new}|\mathbf{x})=P(x_{new})$ and:

[image]

So here are my questions:

1-Why does $P(x_{new}|\mathbf{x})=\int_{\Theta}P(x_{new}|\theta,\mathbf{x})P(\theta|\mathbf{x})d\theta$ hold?

2-If so then Why is use it worth since I'm able to evaluate $P(x_{new}|\mathbf{x})$ by the second figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p(x_{new}|x)$ is the posterior predictive distribution. It can be computed as an integral over the parameter $\theta$ as stated in your question, in fact this is just an application of marginal probability density functions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution): $p(x_{new}|x)=\int_\theta p(x_{new},\theta|x) d\theta$.

$p(x_{new})$ is the prior predictive distribution. $p(x_{new}|x)$ is never equal to $p(x_{new})$ except in trivial cases, because  $x_{new}$ is not independent of $x$. When the slides mention independence of $x$ and $x_{new}$, they actually mean independence *conditional on $\theta$* i.e. the only 'connection' between $x$ and $x_{new}$ is via the parameter $\theta$.

Conditional independence (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence): in this context it means that $p(x_{new}|x,\theta)=p(x_{new}|\theta)$. This is a standard assumption that is made in Bayesian modelling. It's particularly clear that this is reasonable if, say, the data are (conditionally) independent Bernoulli trials with parameter $p$. If we know $p$, then knowing the outcome of any number of Bernoulli trials ($x$) won't tell us anything more about the outcome of future trials ($x_{new}$) (because they're conditionally independent). If we don't know $p$, then $x$ can tell us a lot about $x_{new}$ (because they're not independent).

If conditional independence doesn't hold, we can still proceed but the computations might be more complex. This might happen if, for example, $x$ comprises observation of a continuous time stochastic process over a time interval $[0,T]$ and $x_{new}$ is observations over the future interval $(T,T+1]$.

Comment: What do you mean by 'independence conditional on θ' and why** is that true or even reasonable?

Comment: I made some edits...

Comment: it sounds like $x$ is an useless information if we know $\theta$ and it pretty makes sense.There is just a problem remaining, I didn't stated $P(x_{new}|x)=\int_{\theta} p(x_{new},\theta|x)d\theta$ I do $P(x_{new}|x)=\int_{\theta} p(x_{new}|\theta ,x)p(\theta|x)d\theta$ and your link just tell us about two random variables and its marginalization not 3 as we are in. (It actually tell us a little bit in the end's page but it doesnt use conditional regarding.)

Comment: The two integrands in your comment are equal. This is because $P(A,B|C)=P(A|B,C)P(B|C)$

Comment: great, thank you